# I am looking to delete a dynamically created div in from a dynamically created button in javascript. I am stuck

Tags: javascript

This is my JS code.  I created an input field with a button.  Once the button is clicked, it will output a delete button and a `div` (card) that was created in JS.

The problem I am having is targeting that delete button and deleting that `div`. Everything works except for the very last function `remove()`.

```
let create = document.getElementById("create");
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let output = document.getElementById("output");

create.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = input.value;
    newBtn();
    newDiv();

});

function newBtn () {
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
    let box = document.createTextNode("Delete");
    deleteBtn.appendChild(box);
    document.body.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    //deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", remove.document.createElement("box"));
}

function newDiv () {
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.id = "divBox";
    newDiv.innerHTML = "made div";
    newDiv.style.height = "150px";
    newDiv.style.width = "500px";
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
}

function remove (event) {
    let currentDiv = event.currentTarget.className;
    let removeCard = document.getElementById("currentDiv");
    deleteBtn.removeChild(removeCard);
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that the initial input field and submit button was created in HTML. the div and delete button was created in JS.

Comment: Can you explain which div are you trying to delete?  The div ids in `getElementById` function you've provided don't match.

Comment: The div I’m trying to delete is what’s created in function newDiv(). I’m trying to delete it with the button that’s created in the newBtn ()

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function() { 
  var box = document.getElementById("divBox");
  box.parentNode.removeChild(box);
});
```

Comment: that wont work for me unless i'm putting it in the wrong position in my code.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle that fixes the issue. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zdjck8q/)

```
deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", remove);
```

You had commented out the listener to check for clicking on the delete button in `newBtn()`

```
function remove(event) {
  let div = document.getElementById('divBox');
  document.body.removeChild(div);
}
```

I've updated the remove function to access the div created in the `newDiv()` by referencing its `id`.

Note that your `newBtn()` function will create a delete button every time you click on `Create`.  You can check if the button exists before creating it.

Comment: Thank you. It works just fine, I appreciate the help.